# Is there a way to automatically display “*” required icon beside the [Required] fields

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have finished my asp.net MVC web application, and I have been using the data annotation [Required] to mention that the field is required. But currently the required fields does not have any indication that they are required, unless the user tried to submit the form. So is there way to force my Razor view to display a red “*” beside any field that have [Required] defined on it? OR I need to manually add the “*” icon ?
Thanks

Comment: Do you want the star beside the input or the label for the input?

Comment: i prefer beside the label, i use Html.DisplayNameFor() to display labels

Answer (score 2):

After I got burned by the Bootstrap 2 to 3 upgrade, where they pretty much completely changed the HTML for form controls, I've been putting the entire form group in editor templates instead of just the field. Here's an example:

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("", new { @class = string.Format("control-label col-md-2{0}", ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired ? string.Empty : " optional") })
    <div class="col-md-6">
        @Html.TextBox("", ViewData.TemplateInfo.FormattedModelValue.ToString(), new { type = "email", @class = "form-control" })
        @Html.ValidationMessage("")        
    </div>
</div>
```

What's important here for you is the `string.Format` in `Html.Label`. I'm using the `ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired` to add an "optional" class if it's false. Bootstrap makes the labels bold by default, so as a required indicator, I make optional field labels normal (non-bold). However, adding a `*` is a little more difficult. You could use the same thing I'm doing here to add an additional span tag:

```
@if (ViewData.ModelMetadata.IsRequired)
{
    <span class="requiredIndicator>*</span>
}
@Html.Label(...)
...
```

The potential problem is that that won't actually be *inside* your `<label>` tag, so you might have to do some extra styling work to make it look right depending on the styles you apply to the labels.

An alternative is to create your own HtmlHelper to return a label with a required indicator. Here's some sample code for that:

```
public static MvcHtmlString RequiredIndicatorLabelFor<TModel, TValue>(
    this HtmlHelper<TModel> html,
    Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> modelProperty,
    object htmlAttributes)
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(modelProperty, html.ViewData);
    var labelText = metadata.IsRequired ? string.Format("* {0}", metadata.GetDisplayName()) : metadata.GetDisplayName();
    return html.LabelFor(modelProperty, labelText, htmlAttributes);
}
```

Comment: and then i should manually add the RequiredIndicatorLabelFor all the required field inside my view ? what i was trying to achieve is to have the "*" displayed automatically, rather than manully modifying my views..

Comment: You would just use that instead of `LabelFor` for everything. If it's a required field, it'll prefix the `*`; if not, it will just return a normal label.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but i got an error message the the "Error 2 No overload for method 'LabelFor' takes 3 arguments 
"

Comment: Not sure why. There very much is an overload for that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833693(v=vs.118).aspx. Make sure you add a using for `System.Web.Mvc` in the cs file that holds this static class.

Comment: yes i use the system.Web.mvc already ,,, i am in the mood of adding these * manully what do u suggest ?

Answer (score 1):

You can also write a custom label helper for this purpose

```
public static MvcHtmlString CustomLabelFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression, 
    IDictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = null )
{
    var metadata = ModelMetadata.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData);
    var propertyName = ExpressionHelper.GetExpressionText(expression);
    var builder = new TagBuilder("label");
    builder.Attributes.Add("for", TagBuilder.CreateSanitizedId(htmlHelper.ViewContext.ViewData.TemplateInfo.GetFullHtmlFieldName(propertyName)));
    var labelText = string.Format("{0}{1}", metadata.IsRequired ? "*" : string.Empty,
                                  string.IsNullOrEmpty(metadata.DisplayName)
                                      ? metadata.PropertyName
                                      : metadata.DisplayName);
    builder.SetInnerText(labelText);
    builder.MergeAttributes<string, object>(htmlAttributes, true);
    return new MvcHtmlString(builder.ToString());
}
```

Now when used CustomLabelFor on a property with Required attribute, it will append * in fort of the label text.

```
 @Html.CustomLabelFor(m => m.YourRequiredField)
```

Comment: it partially work but i have the following three problems.I have a label named "site name" but this will be displayed as "Site *Name" so the * will be between the two words instrad of at the end. also the * will be black and not red. third problem is that the html.DisplayNameFor was showing the html.DisplayFor on the same line , while the customLabelFor will display the html.Displayfor on a new line . can you advice on this please ?

Comment: Do you mean that you have a Display("Site Name") and you want * to be in the middle? and in different style?

Comment: For different style you can wrap * star in a span inside of the CustomLabelFor helper using TagBuilder class, and set different style.

Comment: no i want the * to be at the end of the label, but currently it is being displayed in the middle

Comment: hmm interesting, never seen that with this helper, can you post your model property definition with attributes & and what is the output on the page. As far as * being at the end you can just switch string.Format parameters to be {1}{0} instead of {0}{1} and start will be at the end.

Comment: yes using {0}{1} have solved the position problem, but still the Html.Displayfor that comes after the CustomLabelFor will be dipslayed in a new line..

Comment: @Html.CustomLabelFor(m => m.RequiredField, new Dictionary<string, object>() { { "style", "display: inline;" } } ) try this than